# Name typedef directly from scanf

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, typedef

Lets say I have a custom type

```
typedef struct {
    char code[3];
    int max_capacity;
    int state;
} Train;
```

I want to fill an array of these structs using scanf to read a 3char code, the issue is, I want to name the "Train" type directly with the input from scanf without having to attribute a "placeholder name" like ***A*** before retrieving the scanf value.

So lets say I input TRI for example I want to name it TRI as well as TRI.code = TRI

So, avoid something like this

```
void add_train(){
Train A
scanf(“%s”, &A.code)
```

And try to name it directly

```
void add_train(){
Train scanfstring
scanf(“%s”, &scanfstring.code)
```

What would be the best way to go about this without multiple scanf calls or attributions?

Comment: No you cannot. How would you refer to the variable name if it depends on user's input? It just doesn't make sense.

Also, your `char code[3];` needs at least 4 cells. An extra one is for null terminator.

Comment: Huh? Variable names must be known at compile-time (and are not known at run-time)

Comment: I'm very new to c programming and programming in general so I might be missing something obvious. So should I use a placeholder variable name first and then copy it over to a renamed variable after I get the value from scanf?

Comment: None of what you are saying makes any sense. Decide on your variable name while you are writing your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
Struct transporter {
   int max_capacity;  int state;  
};   


typedef struct transporter Train;

    Void add_train() {//assumed not parameterized
    Train TRI[3];
     int code =3;
    (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    scanf(“%d %d”, &TRI[i].max_cpacity, TRI[i].state);
}
```

//I put the code as far as whar I understood from his explainatation which is so confusing.
// okay these block says that you have an transporter collection and you want to inherit a train from it. Typedef for this purpose but I believe you dont even need you can chane "transporters" to "train". 
// and finally he put Not parameterazed function i didnt change; every time you call this function you will create three trains and with for loop you are able to enter capacity and state in the same line for each train